# how to limit the systemctl service in order to avoid memory leak

Tags: linux, centos, rhel, systemctl

I want to share the following idea and understand if this is the right way to limit systemctl service to consume memory more than usual

for example, let's say that we want to limit some service to not eat more then 2G memory

then my suggestion is to do the following:

```
[Service]
MemoryAccounting=yes
MemoryCurrent=2097152 
MemoryLimit=2097152
```

now the big question is what happened when service is reached the 2G as above settings?

there are some options as

1. service will fail
2. service will restart

but we prefer of course that service will restart when consuming of memory reached the limit of 2G

reference -

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/resource_management_guide/sec-modifying_control_groups

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/resource_management_guide/sec-modifying_control_groups

https://superuser.com/questions/1761261/redhat-machine-rsyslogd-eating-up-10-gb

Comment: Adding *Restart=on-failure* to the [service] section ?

Comment: seems to me good idea but you sure about this?

Comment: As @MC68020 said try using that directive and set the other directives `MemoryCurrent=2097152`,`MemoryLimit=2097152 ` to a shorter value for testing.

Comment: yes I can test it it small value and see the behavior, bit I am also want to get professional answer, actually not found documentation from my question

Comment: *Restart=always* possibly be better. BTW would you hold *man systemd.service* (restart §) as a *professional answer* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Systemd uses Cgroup to implement resource constraints, so if your service tries to go over 2 GB memory, Cgroup kills it for you. If you want to ensure it restarts, add `Restart=on-failure` or `Restart=on-abort` (and maybe `StartLimitIntervalSec`).

From [systemd.resource-control](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html):

> MemoryMax=*bytes* ... This controls the `memory.max` control group attribute.

Note that at the time of writing this answer, systemd is already 252 and `MemoryLimit` has been deprecated (it's a cgroup v1 option), so it's no longer on the documentation page.

From [cgroup v2 documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v2.txt) on `memory.max`:

> If a cgroup's memory usage reaches this limit and can't be reduced, the OOM killer is invoked in the cgroup.